# How to bind a handler in go-restful?

Tags: rest, go, go-restful

Go-restful is a good and easy to use Go RESTful style framework, but here is something i am wondering about (this is just a piece of code):

---

```
func main() {
    service := new(restful.WebService)

    service.Route(
    service.GET("/{user-id}").To(FindUser).
    Returns(200, "hello", noMessageValue).
    Returns(500, "internal error", noMessageValue))
    restful.Add(service)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This code can work well. Notice the last line `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`, it does not pass any handler to the ListenAndServe method (it passes a nil value instead), just the port string. Does anyone know how go-restful implements handler binding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `nil` as a handler is a common practice in Go. As the [specs say](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe),

> Handler is typically nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is used.

`DefaultServeMux` is just a convenience global variable in `http`. So, go-restful just [uses it](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/7dd77babc0fbac18c02f6968b4dcf69e9c43bc73/web_service_container.go#L16) by default.